# CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, criteria

Boa noite. Por favor, eu gostaria de lhes pedir ajuda para o código abaixo. Ele me retorna o valor total(valores totais, salvo no banco de dados), mas eu preciso retornar por mês. Já tentei tudo que eu conhecia, mas não consegui resolver o problema. Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("belezaPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(BigDecimal.class);

    Root<Venda> venda = criteriaQuery.from(Venda.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(builder.sum(venda.<BigDecimal> get("precoTotal")));

    TypedQuery<BigDecimal> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    BigDecimal totalVendas = query.getSingleResult();

    System.out.println("A soma das vendas é: R$" + totalVendas);
```

Comment: Qual é o nome de campo que contem a data da venda?

Comment: Olá Augusto, me desculpe pelo atrazo. O campo se chama horario.

Answer (score 1):

Use o método [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjixa/index.html) da interface `CriteriaBuilder`que testa a primeira expressão para ver se esta está entre a segunda e terceira expressão.

No exemplo uso seu código para soma as vendas no mês de abril.
Única alteração significativa no seu código é o trecho em destaque:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("belezaPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(BigDecimal.class);

Root<Venda> venda = criteriaQuery.from(Venda.class);


// ***********************************************************************
Date dataInicial = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/04/2019");
Date dataFinal= new Date();
criteriaQuery.select(builder.sum(venda.<BigDecimal>get("precoTotal"))).where(builder.between(venda.<Date>get("horario"), dataInicial, dataFinal)); 
// ***********************************************************************

TypedQuery<BigDecimal> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
BigDecimal totalVendas = query.getSingleResult();

System.out.println("A soma das vendas em abril é: R$" + totalVendas);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Augusto. Vou tetstar agora mesmo.

Comment: @RubensCostadaSilva. Tinha um erro. Fiz a edição.

Comment: Boa tarde Augusto. Eu refiz, ou melhor acrescentei as linhas que você me passou. Criei o arquivo filtro de datas. Ficou tudo OK, exceto por pequeno detalhe como abaixo: está dando um erro que eu não consegui entender que é o get: criteriaQuery.select(builder.sum(venda.<BigDecimal>get("precoTotal")))
  .where(builder.between(order.<Date>get("horario"), dataInicial, dataFinal));

Comment: O erro no "get", já foi corrigido. Agora vou testar para ver se retorna os valores por mês.

Comment: Bravo! Funcionou. Muito obrigado caro Augusto. Agora posso continuar com o meu projeto graças à sua inestimável ajuda. Muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para retornar o valor total de vendas por mês, você pode adicionar uma cláusula GROUP BY na sua consulta. No seu caso, você pode agrupar os registros de vendas por mês, utilizando a função MONTH do CriteriaBuilder.

Veja um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<Venda> venda = criteriaQuery.from(Venda.class);

Expression<Integer> monthExpression = builder.function("MONTH", Integer.class, venda.get("dataVenda"));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(monthExpression, builder.sum(venda.get("precoTotal")));
criteriaQuery.groupBy(monthExpression);

TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Object[]> resultado = query.getResultList();

for (Object[] linha : resultado) {
    Integer mes = (Integer) linha[0];
    BigDecimal total = (BigDecimal) linha[1];
    System.out.println("Total de vendas no mês " + mes + ": R$" + total);
}
```

Nesse exemplo, o resultado da consulta será uma lista de arrays de objetos, onde cada array representa uma linha do resultado da consulta, contendo o mês e o total de vendas nesse mês.